# How to get Brand Master Account name with child account's username and apikey

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have the username and apikey for a child account, want to get its brand master account? Is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to get information from a higher level account, in this case if your account is not a brand master account, you will not be able to get the data you want.

To know if your account is a brand master account you can use the below request.

Method: GET

```
 https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getBrandAccountFlag
```

Reference:

https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getBrandAccountFlag/

Only you can see the information from a lower level account.